# Filter by one dimension in Dashboard AWS CloudWatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Well, I have the following metric:

```
Name: error-register
Namespace: app2021
Dimensions: ErrorCode, Table, CorrelationId
```

My understanding is that Dimensions works like Tags, so I can use it to help me to find a metric in a more efficient way.

Now I'm creating a dashboard that I need to count total Errors by ErrorCode, so I created the following search expression:

```
SEARCH('"error-register"','Sum',300)
```

It returns all *data-points* but group by ErrorCode, Table, and CorrelationId, so I have something like this:

| Time | Value | DimensionsValues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13:50 | 1234 | ErrorCode=503,Table=A,CorrelationId=1 |
| 13:51 | 50 | ErrorCode=503,Table=B,CorrelationId=2 |
| 13:52 | 1 | ErrorCode=503,Table=C,CorrelationId=3 |

Now I need show the following in Graph:

```
ErrorCode=503 --> total 1285
```

But I can't do it, I just can show ErrorCode by Table and CorrelationId.

Any tips ?